# Send command (start/stop) wirelessly to a DC motor from raspberry pi3

Tags: pi-3, wifi, bluetooth

I know we can connect a dc motor with GPIO pins and star/stop/control speed etc. of it. Is there any way to control that motor wirelessly(over wifi/bluetooth) from raspberry pi? Raspberry pi in one room, dc motor on the other room. No physical connection between them.

I want to control the motor from a different room in my house. How do i do it?

Comment: I think you can connect your smart phone to Rpi, using BlueTooth or Wifi. Then you can use GUI apps to click buttons, or send text commands to Rpi. So first thing first is to starting googling with key words, "Rpi", "smart phone", "Wifi", "Bluetooth", "app", "connection" etc.  Or you can start googling Youtube videos on "Android phone Wifi garage opener" etc to get some idea of how to DIY your own Rpi WiFi motor starter/stopper.

Comment: you'll need something connected to the motor that can connect to bluetooth/wifi and accept commands from the pi

Comment: @JaromandaX do you know any hardware that exist like that. after googling, i can only find like motorair v2 kinda of things. do you know if that can receive command from raspberry pi?